# Trying to scope the users information

Tags: angularjs

I need to use the current user his id for a filter on a ng-repeat. I'm still trying to get a good grasp on Angular, so my assumption may be wrong. But I was thinking if I can put the current users information (name, id, email etc) in a scope, I can then use that scope to insert the id into the filter in the Angular controller.

So I've created `users_controller.rb`

```
def index
  respond_with current_user
end
```

So it only shows the current user his information.

I've added a resource to my `routes.rb`

```
resources :users
```

Then I created a factory to retrieve the JSON information in my `userService.js`

```
.factory('userService', [
  '$http', function($http) {
    return {
      loadUsers: function() {
        return $http.get(('/users.json'),{ cache: true}).
          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            if (status == 200) {
              console.log('Succes')
            } else {
              console.error('Error happened while getting the user list.')
            }

          })
      }
    };
  }
])
```

Then console log in the browser says `succes`, so I'm assuming it's retrieving the data from the users.json file.

And then in my `mainController.js` I created a function that saves the response data from the factory service in a scope

```
  userService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
  });

  console.log ($scope.users)
```

But this `console.log` gives a result of `undefined`. So my first question is, does anyone know why I'm getting a `undefined` instead of the information of the current user.

My second question is, if we work out the first problem and I can store the information in a `$scope.users` is it possible to use that information in my controller like so?

```
  var user_id = $scope.user.id
  $scope.user_id = user_id;
```

Comment: are you injecting that filter as a dependency  to your main controller?

Comment: `loadUsers()` is asynchronous....you can't log the data until it is returned

Comment: @FarzadYZ Yes I inject `userService` in my controller.

Comment: One implementation could be to resolve users data before the view is loaded, have you tried that?

Comment: @charlietfl ah, so the maincontroller does the console.log action before the service could fill it? So it would be better to scope the data inside the service and then use that scope in the maincontroller?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma the scope object is not available in service, it is only available in controller to link views and models and on directives as isolated scope.

Comment: Your view will display `$scope.users` fine when the data does arrive. The `then` will tell angular to run a digest to update view

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not using the `$scope.users` in my view, but I want to use the data in my `maincontroller`

Comment: But you are showing it already being in your main controller. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @charlietfl The last part in my opening posts about the variable is a example pf what I am trying to accomplish. But I don´t know if I can use a scope like that in my controller.

Comment: You do it in the `then` callback. You can already use it in the view without creating a new variable also. Having seen the problems you are having over multiple questions I think you need to spend some more time studying tutorials. Seem to be lacking some of the javascript fundamentals that are needed to work within angular

Comment: The funny thing is that I thought that `$scope.users.id` wouldn't work because it's so obvious. But it actually works, I created a $scope with the users id and inside the `succes` I used my variable and I'm now getting the correct result. While I do agree with you that I need more knowledge of Javascript it is very hard to pinpoint the essence of a Angular problem. But in my opinion it takes a while before people know how to get to the heart of the matter. I do want to thank you for your help and patiance.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question:

AngularJS is asynchronous, it follows that `$http` service is asynchronous, thus you are getting undefined (because `console.log` is run before the `$http` service is even completed)

Your second question:

If you are using `$scope.user_id` (which by my assumption stores the current user id? It isn't defined elsewhere) as a filter (which is perfectly fine, although you might need to define your own since it's a bi vague in the question), you'll need to assign it inside the `$http` service (not outside). Or you can chain some promise to assign it only after the `$http` request has been completed. Although in my opinion, if you are just using the current user id to filter out an array of users, you shouldn't use `ng-repeat` for this and then tell AngularJS to use some custom filter. AngularJS will create a bunch of watchers for each element in `ng-repeat` and it will also do a lot of other things to keep track in case of events in the DOM or the script change the view. (which I'm guessing it won't)

If I'm right about that, you should just manually filter it out using a `angular.forEach` or `for` loop and have that sent to your view